# List of all nested subfolders with a specific name

Tags: linux

How to get a list of all the subfolders with a specific name
e.g. all the folders which their name contains 'NAME'

I know:

```
find . | grep *NAME*
```

but this won't give me a unique list (if the folder has subfolders it gets listed multiple times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
find . -type d -name "*name*"
```

(or use `-iname` if you want a case insensitive match)